# add different dictionaries in one dictionary in python 3

Tags: python, dictionary

I have many dictionaries dict1,dict2,dict3, that all have the same keys but different values and I want to make all of them in the same dictionary . an someone help me!
this is the content of the dictionaries.

[image]

Comment: Images are not encouraged here. Please copy-paste the code here.

Comment: What have you done so far ? Also what do you want the formatted data to look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst_dict = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
dict_final = {}
for d in dict1.keys():
  dict_final[d] = tuple(dict_final[d] for dict_final in lst_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution..

```
lista = [
    [{'fruit': 'apple', 'price': 100}],
    [{'fruit': 'banana', 'price': 200}],
    [{'fruit': 'chikoo', 'price': 300}],
    [{'fruit': 'dragon fruit', 'price': 400}],
    [{'fruit': 'elder berry', 'price': 500}]
]

fruit = []
price = []

for i in lista:
    for j in i:
        for k, v in j.items():
            if 'fruit' == k:
                fruit.append(v)
            if 'price' == k:
                price.append(v)

print('---fruit---', fruit)
print('---price---', price)
```

output:

```
---fruit--- ['apple', 'banana', 'chikoo', 'dragon fruit', 'elder berry']
---price--- [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

Note:

- just replace your dict to respect of lista
- create empty list of each key
- append if statement for each key